# Application recycle problems

Tags: paas

We upgraded from Sitecore 8.1 to 9.0 some weeks ago, and we moved to Azure PaaS. Since then we are suffering from application recycles in some of our instances.

Looking at event viewer, we saw tens of "recycles" of a concrete page due to "Global configuration changed" like the following in some of the instances

```
<Event>
<System>
<Provider Name="HttpPlatformHandler"/>
<EventID>2000</EventID>
<Level>4</Level>
<Task>0</Task>
<Keywords>Keywords</Keywords>
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2018-12-12T06:32:29Z"/>
<EventRecordID>798817468</EventRecordID>
<Channel>Application</Channel>
<Computer>............</Computer>
<Security/>
</System>
<EventData>
<Data>Global configuration changed. Change path: MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/....WEBAPP__89A7/...../MyPage, ApplicationManager: 0000013AD53DFBB0 [TID 2516] [PID 7800]</Data>
</EventData>
</Event>
<Event>
<System>
<EventData>
<Data>Recycling application MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/....WEBAPP__89A7/...../MyPage [TID 2516] [PID 7800]</Data>
</EventData>
```

And sometimes we saw a global configuration change on a concrete instance that cause recycles on all the web apps and their not being able to server requests for some minutes.

```
<Event>
<System>
<Provider Name="HttpPlatformHandler"/>
<EventID>2000</EventID>
<Level>4</Level>
<Task>0</Task>
<Keywords>Keywords</Keywords>
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2018-12-14T08:04:54Z"/>
<EventRecordID>1396347156</EventRecordID>
<Channel>Application</Channel>
<Computer>.........</Computer>
<Security/>
</System>
<EventData>
<Data>Change in global configuration [TID 3296] [PID 13784]</Data>
</EventData>
</Event>
<Event>
<System>
<Provider Name="HttpPlatformHandler"/>
<EventID>2000</EventID>
<Level>4</Level>
<Task>0</Task>
<Keywords>Keywords</Keywords>
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2018-12-14T08:04:54Z"/>
<EventRecordID>1396347218</EventRecordID>
<Channel>Application</Channel>
<Computer>......</Computer>
<Security/>
</System>
<EventData>
<Data>Global configuration changed. Change path: MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/SITECORE-CD-WEBAPP__89A7, ApplicationManager: 00000216AA53FE90 [TID 3296] [PID 13784]</Data>
</EventData>
</Event>
<Event>
<System>
<Provider Name="HttpPlatformHandler"/>
<EventID>2000</EventID>
<Level>4</Level>
<Task>0</Task>
<Keywords>Keywords</Keywords>
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2018-12-14T08:04:54Z"/>
<EventRecordID>1396347265</EventRecordID>
<Channel>Application</Channel>
<Computer>......</Computer>
<Security/>
</System>
<EventData>
<Data>Recycling application MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/SITECORE-CD-WEBAPP__89A7 [TID 3296] [PID 13784]</Data>
</EventData>
</Event>
```

Is anyone suffering a similar problem? Any idea what can cause a configuration change in a specific instance, not affecting the other ones?

Investigating the issue we found people experiencing similar problems with Sitecore 9 on Windows Server 2012, that can be fixed with a Windows update:

https://www.clearpeople.com/insights/blog/2018/november/sitecore-9-restarts-multiple-times-on-windows-2012.

But I wouldn't expect that Microsoft hadn't applied this hotfix to its Azure web apps.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you look in the Sitecore logs to see if it tells you specifically what files are being modified?

Comment: I checked, not clue in logs.

Comment: Are you getting any errors on the front end when this happens? Had an issue very similar and was receiving 503 Gateway timeout error. Sitecore provided a patch for it.

Comment: @justin It restart suddenly sometimes with errors 500 just before others not. We haven't find yet any pattern. Can you provide me the kb sitecore of the patch to investigate?

Comment: @MarcCals - here is the KB - https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/910936

Comment: What version? 9.0.0, 9.0.1, or 9.0.2?

Comment: Hi @PeteNavarra, It's Sitecore 9.0.1

Comment: @MarcCals did you ever figure this out? I am facing the same issue on PaaS 9.1.

Comment: Hi @MartinEnglish, No we still facing the same issue. Microsfot it's investigating and they said could be for server update, outages on their infrastructue. But honestly we see this recycles to much often to be due to azure outages or server updates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally we find the problem, it´s due to an Azure problem with slots, unrelated with Sitecore.

We were able to recreate the issue to Azure with a blank web app, just doing a manual swap, any scale out done after the swap cause the web app to restart.

The issue description to Azure was: "After customer does a swap as mentioned, on the next change notification, the application host config will get updated binding information to reflect the swapped hostnames of the slots. However, this isn’t triggered by the swap, but rather happens as a result of the swap. It can happen that the next change notification doesn’t come for a few hours or in fact even a few days when austocale is done."

Resuming the swap it´s doing a change in a config file, that it´s not noticed at the moment of swapping, it´s noticed when the autoscale it´s done, causing a restart of the wep app due to a change in a config file.

To avoid this problem it´s just so easy as add the following setting to the web app

```
WEBSITE_ADD_SITENAME_BINDINGS_IN_APPHOST_CONFIG=1
```

More info in https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Configurable-settings

Answer (score 1):

Your app might be initiating the recycle due to a [Proactive Auto Heal](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2018/09/10/announcing-the-new-auto-healing-experience-in-app-service-diagnostics/). Usually this means that memory is getting dangerously high or it has detected a memory leak that will cause OutOfMemoryExceptions.

This feature can be disabled, however I recommend you leave it enabled and try fix the root cause of the issue.

I've found that scaling up the hosting plan to one with more memory and cores also helps, but again it's only a band-aid fix.

Comment: Hi @MarkGibbons. We checked and It´s not the proactive auto heal neither a memory leak. The memory stills always around 5Gb.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Azure Dynamic cache can cause such issues, you can try disabling it in App settings WEBSITE_DYNAMIC_CACHE=0.

See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2017/08/02/asp-net-and-asp-net-core-application-restarts-on-azure-app-service/

Comment: We had this setting enabled from month ago and make not difference.
Thanks!